# ¿Cómo descargar una imagen por medio de una url con id usando CURL en PHP?

Tags: php, curl

Como se puede descargar una imagen por medio de una url, esta url no contiene el nombre de la imagen ni la extensión, se hace referencia a la imagen por medio de su ID.
Ejemplo de la URL de la imagen: https://4promotional.net:9090/WsEstrategia/imagesWeb/imagenExtra?id=32%20OZ

Todas las imágenes se descargan en jpg.

Código usado:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://4promotional.net:9090/WsEstrategia/imagesWeb/imagenExtra?id=32%20OZ");
$fp = fopen("imagen.jpg", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir cuando hablas de *descargar*? Por otra parte, si la imagen está en la petición cURL, no estás usando el resultado de dicha petición. Deberías guardar una referencia de la misma, por ejemplo: `$img=curl_exec($ch);` y luego *descargar*  `$img`.

Comment: me refiero a bajar el archivo que contiene la URL y guardarlo en una carpeta.
Si el código que muestro se usa para descargar otra imagen usando URL's como estas:
www.ejmeplo/imagen.jpg
www.ejmeplo/imagen.png
www.ejmeplo/imagen.jpeg

No se tiene ningún problema pero por alguna razón al usar el código en URL's como la que puse en el inicio, no se descarga, envía un archivo con error.
Intentare ejecutar tu recomendación.